# Whats the fastest way to get range complement?

Tags: c#, c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to get range complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925514/fastest-way-to-get-range-complement)

I have a sorted array of nonoverlaping ranges  for example (0,2],(2,4],(6,9] and I wish to get it's complement with (0,12] which shoud return (4,6],(9,12] .Whats the fastest way to do that?

Comment: I tray to look for entire range that iI wish to check and for each value check if it is part of each range in array , then loop again so I wold build ranges of every two numbers which diference is bigger than one. My problem is that I use this to cache file content so I'm dealing with big numbers .

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. If you can improve your original question, feel free to edit it and flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your input data is an array of this form:

```
{ 0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 9 }
```

Simply add the new elements 0 and 12 to the beginning and end, and you have

```
{ 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12 }
```

And reinterpreting consecutive pairs as intervals, you have:

- (0, 0]
- (2, 2]
- (4, 6]
- (9, 12]

The fact that you have degenerate intervals makes this something of a mess, but if your original list did not have any degenerate intervals, your output list would not either.

Depending on the format of your data and whether you can do in-place modification, this operation may be `O(1)`.

Comment: What if I have  for example (3,13] or a value thats comletly in one or two regions?

Comment: @apaka: Just remove empty intervals from the final list.  In your example, you would have the empty interval (13, 12].

Comment: I meant what if I check(3.13] against array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it takes O(*n*) assuming *n* as the size of the sorted array. 
Because you should check the gap between every adjacent ranges.

P.S. I guess it is your homework!

Answer (score 0):

- create one list of 2*n numbers. {a[0] .. a[2n-1]} by merging all intervals.  It's sorted by construction.
- ignore the pairs (a[i], a[i+1]) where i is odd and a[i]==a[i+1].
- put at the front the lowest possible value.
- put at the back the highest possible value.
- splice two by two, you obtain the complement.